# How can I parameterize SQL search criteria?

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters, sql-injection, query-builder

With a select statement like the following:

```
Select ID, Fname, Lname, 
from Users 
where Fname @searchCriteria @Fname

Util.AddParameters(“@Fname”, tbFname.value, SqlDbType.nvarchar)
```

How would I do the same with the search criteria?

```
Util.AddParameters(“@searchCriteria”, =, )
```

Comment: Use string concatenation: `"SELECT ID, Fname, Lname, FROM Users WHERE Fname " & searchCriterion & " @Fname"`. Don't let the user enter the value of the variable `searchCriterion` directly.

Comment: You can only use parameters for values, no other part of the SQL code can be provided via a parameter; not keywords, not identifiers and not operators. The only way you could do that was if you had a stored procedure that took those parts as text and constructed secondary SQL internally and then executed it. There's little point to that here though. As suggested, use concatenation for that part but ensure the user chooses from valid values and cannot enter their own malicious SQL fragment.